# Accessing the file of sub directory in a better way

Tags: c++, boost

I have a directory test and a subdirectory metadata. 
`C:/Users/name/Desktop/test/metadata\\test_1.metadata`.
I access the file inside metadata directory this way.

```
std::string filename = dir_iter->path().string();
std::string rawName = filename.substr( 0 , filename.find_last_of( "." ) ); 
std::string subRawDir = rawName.substr( 0 , rawName.find_last_of( "\\" ) ) + "/metadata\\";
std::string name = subRawDir + rawName.substr( filename.find_last_of( "\\" ) + 1 ) + ".metadata";
```

A better approach than this would be nice :)

Comment: Initiallly, the path is a file from a test directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to boost::filesystem. It gives you many functions to iterate trhough directories, sub-directories and files. 
You can find tutorial and explanation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

Here an example on how to do that:

```cpp
  #include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
  #include <boost/foreach.hpp> 

  boost::filesystem::path your_dir("C:/Users/name/Desktop/test/metadata"); 

  boost::filesystem::directory_iterator it(your_dir), end_of_dir;

  BOOST_FOREACH(boost::filesystem::path const &p, std::make_pair(it, end_of_dir))   
  { 
       if(is_regular_file(p))
       {
          // Do stuff with your file
       } 
  }
```

Comment: The issue is that I have to save the path of test directory file and pass it to another function and check if file inside metadata directory exists or not, If it doesn't exists the file is created and filled. So, I have made 4 variables. The iteration inside a sub directory is not an issue. I wish to use less variables and access the sub directory in a better way.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your problem. You need to extract the subdirectory name (i.e. /metadata) or the filename (i.e., test_1.metadata)?

Comment: The test directory exists. However it's uncertain that files like test_1.metadata exists or not. If the file  doesn't exists , it has to be created. Also the original path has to be saved which is inside a test directory , not inside the metadata directory for further purpose. Might be I made it clear :). I guess REGEX makes it simpler, but I am null with REGEX.

Comment: But to save the test directory ("C:/Users/name/Desktop/test") you can still use boost to access this string value with no regex. Boost allows you to iterate through the directory tree, thus, you can obtain not only absolute paths to files, but also relative paths or paths to sub-directories. I mean, you can have access to each part of the path (Users, name, User/name, test, test/metadata, test/metadata\\test1.metadata...) without annoying substring stuff, by just using boost methods. That should give you everything you need to create the file or store path infos